# Access network share remotely without routing all traffic through VPN tunnel

Tags: vpn, samba, windows-server-2016, share

I would like to be able to access a network share that is running off my Windows Server 2016 Datacenter server remotely. I realize that I can create a VPN server by using the Remote Access feature and then connect my client to it, but my challenge is that I would not want the client to tunnel all of it's traffic through my server. I only want to grant the client access to the share whilst keeping all of it's other traffic going through it's normal network.

What would be the best way to do this (if possible at all?)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this would be adding a static route pointing at the remote VPN tunnel end for an IP host or network address of the server hosting this share. This is also the most obvious way.

Comment: To benefit the OP can you provide a link that can help describe what this “Split-tunneling” scenario looks like?

Comment: Yes please! I'm kinda a noob when it comes to VPN servers.